# Should composer be installed/copied to every project or stored in a single location?

Tags: php, composer-php, file-management

I am working with composer and I've recently started a new project which requires it. No big deal since I've downloaded the json file and vendor folder and whatnot in another project.

Except I have to copy the composer files from my original project's directory and paste them into the new one. Is this the correct way to go about using composer or should I have the files contained within a single external location and referenced by each of my projects?

I'm aware that this is slightly off topic but I couldn't find a straight answer elsewhere and would appreciate advise on the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is okay. Every project folder should have its own composer files. That way, updates or changes to dependencies are isolated per project.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an advanced topic where you can modify php.ini's include path.

You do not need to copy composer vendor files per project. You can specify 'global' as parameter, which will save vendor projects in a global path.

Then, tweak your [php.ini's include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) include that global path's autoload.

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
```

Do NOT put a './' prefix as './vendor/... and the file is included from the global repository. This is a per-user configuration and may be allowed on your linux console.

Your project's json file is attached within the project itslef, but the vendor path is from global. Many projects can share the same repository. It may not impact the performance too much, because autoload does its best.